# OCaml Complicated Name reuse v.s Recursive func. Confusion

Tags: ocaml

I was reading some example and come across this code and google failed me.

```
let id = fun x -> x in fun x -> if x> 0 then id [] else (id x) :: [];;
- : int -> int list = <fun>
```

As Caml tells us this is testified to be a function in general.

But it has "let" instead of "let rec" and the function name id appears in the function body several times on the other hand.

This looks illogical in the first glance.

So I was thinking

```
1. is this actually a recursive function? 

2. Or they just happen to be different types reusing the same name confusingly.
```

Could you show your insightful ideas with clear reasoning standing on concrete base?

Comment: also, the `id` function is defined for scope following it, which, as rightfully explained by the answer of this question, is an anonymous function, hence both are actually unreachable from any statement following this one...

Comment: I was thinking that the whole stuff is called "id"

Comment: Yeah, that's the impression I had from your question. The notation can be misleading for people accustomed to other languages idioms. The `in` keyword there is very important, and may be used even at top level, not only inside functions (your code is a clear illustration of that feature). It's necessary to make the language "behaviour" consistent for end users, and also preferable for the language implementors, as it simplifies the grammar. Good question btw.

Comment: @didierc Good point! Consistent syntax and grammar is quite important for end-users especially for those who just get started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two functions in your code. The first one is `fun x -> x`. This function is not recursive (it just returns `x` unchanged without calling any other function including itself) and it is given the name `id` using `let`.

The other function is `fun x -> if x > 0 then id [] else (id x) :: []`. This function does not have a name. It is also not recursive since the only function that it calls is `id` and `id` doesn't call it back.

The name `id` is not reused in this code. It is only ever used to refer to the function `fun x -> x`. The only name that is being reused is `x`: In the definition of `id` it is used to refer to `id`'s argument and in the definition of the other function it is used to refer to that function's argument.